# Some questions on Makefile

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, embedded

I am trying to understand a second level makefile of uboot (this makefile was in a sub directory)

```
a) What is the difference between $(COBJS:.o=.c) and  COBJS   := test_main.o
b) What is the meaning of $(call cmd_link_o_target, $(OBJS)). What is the cmd_link_o_target and what is the call statement doing
c) Does this line creating 2 targets ?

ALL     :=       $(obj).depend $(LIB)
```

===================================Makefile===================

```
include $(TOPDIR)/config.mk

LIB     = $(obj)libtest.o

SOBJS   := test.o

COBJS   := test_main.o
COBJS   += diagnostic.o


SRCS    := $(SOBJS:.o=.S) $(COBJS:.o=.c)
OBJS    := $(addprefix $(obj),$(COBJS) $(SOBJS))

ALL     :=       $(obj).depend $(LIB)

all:    $(ALL)

$(LIB): $(OBJS)
        $(call cmd_link_o_target, $(OBJS))

#########################################################################

# defines $(obj).depend target
include $(SRCTREE)/rules.mk

sinclude $(obj).depend

#########################################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

a) `$(COBJS:.o=.c)` performs a suffix substitution on every element of `COBJ`  which in this case is equivalent to using `SRCS := test.S test_main.c`

b) `$(call cmd_link_o_target, $(OBJS))` is a way to create a *parametric function* in make. It will take the expression for `cmd_link_o_target` (contained in the included file) and replace every occurence of `$(1)` with `$(OBJS)` further expanded.

c) yes, it does (`obj` is also contained in the file included by the Makefile).

In case you are wondering, the difference between `=` and `:=` assignments is that `=` allows for recursive replacement, while `:=` is *static*, i.e. expanded only once, without creating references to other variables.